# Format proper sql in sql file having newline characters

Tags: python, sql

I have .sql file having lines in following format.

```
CREATE TABLE public.admin_settings (\n  id character varying(31) NOT NULL, \njson_value character varying, \n  key character varying(255)\n);
```

I want to remove `\n` and provide proper indentation as where required but following code only removes the `\n` only an not take it to new line.

```
>>> with open('file.sql', 'r') as file:
...     # read the contents of the file
...     content = file.read()
...
>>> content = content.replace('\n', '')
>>>
>>> with open('fileout.sql', 'w') as file:
...     # write the modified contents back to the file
...     file.write(content)
```

Any help appreciated

Expected output:

```
CREATE TABLE public.admin_settings (
id character varying(31) NOT NULL,
json_value character varying, 
key character varying(255)
);
```

Comment: you could use `content.splitlines()` function and write a logic to split the string

Comment: try this: content = content.replace('\\n', '\n')

Answer (score 0):

If I follow your issue correctly, you have text in your SQL file that should be converted into newlines. I think this does that:

```py
with open('file.sql', 'r') as file:
    content = [
        f"{line.strip()}\n"
        for line in file.read().split("\\n")
    ]

with open('fileout.sql', 'w') as file:
    # write the modified contents back to the file
    file.writelines(content)
```

Comment: This removes the "indentation" after newlines, but doesn't really "make it proper" as requested. So `content.replace('\\n', '\n')` like @Phillip commented is doing the same, but shorter.

Comment: @Jeronimo When I use what I believe is the stated input I get the stated output exactly. The comment while removing the newline issue does not give the stated output.